# How to set Default launcher from Setting programatically?

Tags: android, default, android-launcher

I want to make my Launcher as Default Launcher. My code  is Working properly for many but not wok on LeTtv device.
because it's provide set default launcher from default app setting.

when run this code it's move on default Launcher but not show Launcher chooser Popup only in LeTv Device .

**How to open Default app selection Setting?**

**my Code for Choose default launcher**

```
private void setDefLauncher(Context c) {



    PackageManager p = c.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName cN = new ComponentName(c, FakeLauncher.class);
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    c.startActivity(selector);

    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.launcher.launcher3.Launcher"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:resumeWhilePausing="true"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/Theme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  <activity
            android:name="com.launcher2.activitys.FakeLauncher"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Set Default Launcher manually
**Setting->Application Manager->Default App Setting->Set Launcher**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was search in **Google** ,**StackOverFlow** & **Github** but nothing I found,
by my luck  Some Luncher  help me to redirect HomeStting Activity in Levt & MI  phones, it's work as per my expectation .
In Some it's work perfect ,I just Decompile it and Get used code for it.

for set Default launcher

```
new SetDefaultLauncher(activity).launchHomeOrClearDefaultsDialog();
```

.

```
package com.android.launcher;

import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.TtsSpan.TextBuilder;
import com.example.launcher.R;
import com.launcher2.activitys.FakeLauncher;

public class SetDefaultLauncher {

    public static final String LAUNCHER_CLASS = "com.android.launcher.launcher3.Launcher";
    public static final String LAUNCHER_PACKAGE = "com.android.launcher";

    Activity activity;
    SetDefaultLauncher(Activity activity){
        this.activity=activity;
    }
    enum HomeState {
        GEL_IS_DEFAULT, OTHER_LAUNCHER_IS_DEFAULT, NO_DEFAULT
    }
    public boolean launchHomeOrClearDefaultsDialog() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
        ResolveInfo resolveActivity = activity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(
                intent, 0);
        HomeState homeState = (LAUNCHER_PACKAGE
                .equals(resolveActivity.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName) && LAUNCHER_CLASS
                .equals(resolveActivity.activityInfo.name)) ? HomeState.GEL_IS_DEFAULT
                : (resolveActivity == null
                        || resolveActivity.activityInfo == null || !inResolveInfoList(
                        resolveActivity, activity.getPackageManager()
                                .queryIntentActivities(intent, 0))) ? HomeState.NO_DEFAULT
                        : HomeState.OTHER_LAUNCHER_IS_DEFAULT;
        switch (homeState) {
        case GEL_IS_DEFAULT:
        case NO_DEFAULT:
            intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
            intent.setFlags(268435456);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            showClearDefaultsDialog(resolveActivity);
            return false;
        }
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") private void showClearDefaultsDialog(ResolveInfo resolveInfo) {
        CharSequence string;
        final Intent intent;
        CharSequence loadLabel = resolveInfo.loadLabel(activity.getPackageManager());
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT < 21
                || activity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(
                        new Intent("android.settings.HOME_SETTINGS"), 0) == null) {
            string = activity.getString(R.string.change_default_home_dialog_body,
                    new Object[] { loadLabel });
            intent = new Intent(
                    "android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS",
                    Uri.fromParts("package",
                            resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, null));
        } else {
            intent = new Intent("android.settings.HOME_SETTINGS");
            string = new SpannableString(activity.getString(
                    R.string.change_default_home_dialog_body_settings,
                    new Object[] { loadLabel }));
            ((SpannableString) string)
                    .setSpan(
                            new TextBuilder(
                                    activity.getString(
                                            R.string.change_default_home_dialog_body_settings_tts,
                                            loadLabel)).build(), 0, string
                                    .length(), 18);
        }



        new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setMessage(string)
                .setNegativeButton(
                        activity.getString(R.string.change_default_home_dialog_cancel),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                activity.finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface. OnCancelListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        activity.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton(
                        activity.getString(R.string.change_default_home_dialog_proceed),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                try {
                                    intent.setFlags(276856832);
                                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    setDefLauncher(activity);
                                }
                            }
                        }).create().show();
    }

    private boolean inResolveInfoList(ResolveInfo resolveInfo,
            List<ResolveInfo> list) {
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo2 : list) {
            if (resolveInfo2.activityInfo.name
                    .equals(resolveInfo.activityInfo.name)
                    && resolveInfo2.activityInfo.packageName
                            .equals(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void setDefLauncher(Context c) {
        PackageManager p = c.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName cN = new ComponentName(c, FakeLauncher.class);
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        c.startActivity(selector);
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the FakeLauncher?